# Update a SharePoint Online ListItem without incrementing version

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-api

I would like to update a SharePoint Online list item without incrementing the version.
Before the call, version is **"12.0"**.

I make this call :

POST :

```
/_api/web/lists('ea99ccea-d626-4a60-bfcb-d3cd43705cc8')/Items(27)/validateUpdateListItem
```

Body :

```
{
    "formValues":[
    {
    "FieldName":"Approval_x0020_status",
    "FieldValue":"Approved"
    },
{
"FieldName":"Approver_x0020_comments",
    "FieldValue":""

},
{
    "FieldName":"Modified_x0020_By",
    "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|myuser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
    },
{
    "FieldName":"Editor",
    "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|myuser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
    }
    ],
"bNewDocumentUpdate":true
}
```

But, after this code, and despite the fact that I put **"bNewDocumentUpdate":true** in the call, version is incremented to **"12.1"**.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `Modified_x0020_By` custom column OR you are trying to refer SharePoint default "Modified By" column?

Comment: It's a custom column

Comment: Strange! Your code syntax looks good to me.

Comment: Agree, strange issue. Out of interest, what Headers did you use?

Comment: I use the PowerAutomate SharePoint connector "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" with no specific headers